# "let movie of movies$ | async" not working

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm trying to implement the sample code shown in the official [NgRx docs for effects](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects).  The first section showing how to load a list of movies in an effect works, but the list is not displayed.

I can see the movies array in the Redux dev tools, and the movies$ will appear as "[object Object]" in the template if printed out, but otherwise the template is blank.

The code goes as follows.  The component selects part of the state:

```js
export class MoviesPageComponent {
  movies$: Observable<Movie[]> = this.store.select(state => state.movies); 
  constructor(private store: Store<{ movies: Movie[] }>) {} 
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Movies Page] Load Movies' });
  }
}
```

The template uses the async pipe to show the list:

```html
<div *ngFor="let movie of movies$ | async">
  {{ movie.name }}
</div>
```

The effect calls the service to get the data:

```
  loadMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('[Movies Page] Load Movies'),
    mergeMap(() => this.moviesService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(movies => ({ type: '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success', payload: movies })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );
```

The effect is registered in the app.module like this:

```js
EffectsModule.forRoot([MovieEffects]),
```

The effect works and in the dev tools you can see the movies, but the asyc pipe never shows the list.

I realize this is kind of like pseudo code, but I would like to know what it takes to make these samples run as expected.  I have a [sample repo to test the code here](https://github.com/timofeysie/strict-ten-ngrx).

Any help would be much appreciated!

** edit **

I have create a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ty3eys?file=src/app/app.module.ts).  It's not exactly the same as the repo provided, but could be used to show the solution to this issue.

Comment: In your template try to display all arrays using json, It might be that the movies array is empty. Use json pipe `{{ movies$ | async | json }}`

Comment: You can print `{{ movies$ | async | json }}` and see whats the output it will help to further debug, looks like it has array inside array but print it in template with JSON pipe and see whats the result.

Comment: @OwenKelvin, the same problem happens trying to show the json (ie blank screen).  I have added a [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ty3eys?file=src/app/movies/movies-page.component.ts) to demonstrate.  You can't see the array in the dev tools like you can when running the repo, but the code from the NgRx site is basically the same.

Comment: Your component does not implement `OnInit` interface. Please check if that is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @user2007130, actually, it does.  The dispatch action there is shown to work as the effect is called and the movies shown up as an array in the dev tools.  You can see the code [in the repo here](https://github.com/timofeysie/strict-ten-ngrx/blob/master/src/app/movies/movies-page/movies-page.component.ts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to solve this is first to understand how a store works

- We dispatch an action
- An Effect intercepts the dispatch, processes it and dispatches another action
- A reducer stores the data in the store
- You can now access the store using a the static function on the store, pipeable select operator or my favorite a selector,

Lets have a store in mind,

```
{
  movies: Movie[]
}
```

We can start by defining a store in the app.module.ts

```
// ...
imports: [
  StoreModule.forRoot({ }),
  EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
 // ...
]
```

This produces `{ }` in the store

Next in the movies.module.ts we can define a **feature**

```
// ...
imports: [
  EffectsModule.forFeature([MovieEffects]),
  StoreModule.forFeature('movies', movieReducer),
  // ...
]
```

Now in our store we have { movies: [] }

In the movie reducer we then have below

```
 const _movieReducer = createReducer<Movie[]>(
  initialState,
  on(
    loadMovies,
    (state): Movie[] => ([
      ...state
    ])
  ),

  on(loadMoviesSuccess, (state, action) => ([
    ...state,
    ...action.payload,
  ]))
```

Note we do not need to add `movies` in state, as this was already defined as a feature

[Link to solution on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rhquyi)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @OwenKelvin, I can see everything working in the StackBlitz.  However, using the same code in the repo shows an error in the component ```this.store.select((state) => state.movies);```: *Property 'movies' does not exist on type '{ payload: Movie[]; }'*.  If I change that to state.payload, the app runs, but the result is the same; a blank screen despite the movies array showing up in the dev tools from the '[Movies API] Movies Loaded Success' action.

Comment: After going through the StackBlitz code, I uncovered the issue:  the component constructor had this: ```private store: Store<{ payload: Movie[] }>```.  Changing that to ```movies: Movie[]``` allows the app to run as expected and show the list.  Thanks for the great answer.  Marking as correct.

Comment: Glad it helped!